# How to package a nested Python module using scikit-build?

Tags: cmake, setuptools, python-packaging, pybind11, scikit-build

scikit-build is failing to package a python project for me. Here's the layout

```
hello-cpp
├── src
|   └── hello
|       ├── OtherModule
|       |   └── __init__.py  # empty
|       └── __init__.py      # empty
|       └── hello.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── setup.py
```

contents of `setup.py`:

```
from skbuild import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name="hello-cpp",
    version='0.0.1',
    description="a minimal example package (cpp version)",
    author="Me",
    license="MIT",
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

content of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.22)

project(hello)

find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)

pybind11_add_module(example src/hello/hello.cpp)
install(TARGETS example LIBRARY DESTINATION src/hello)
```

contents of `src/hello/hello.cpp`:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}
```

When running `python -c "from hello import example"` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'`.

Removing `src/hello/OtherModule/__init__.py` allows `scikit-build` to package the module, but I want to have `hello.OtherModule`, so this is not an option.

I have tried installing this via `pip install -e .` as well as `python setup.py develop` and `python -m pip install --editable .` inside a `conda` environment built with `conda create --name so_example python=3.10 scikit-build ninja` and nothing else installed. The `hello.hello` C++ module appears to be properly built by `pybind11`, but the `hello` package itself is not properly installed, despite `pip` claiming that it

> Successfully installed hello-cpp-0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I copied your files into a directory and added a pyproject.toml file:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "scikit-build", "pybind11"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And tried this:

```
$ virtualenv .venv
$ .venv/bin/pip install .
$ tree .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hello
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hello
├── OtherModule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
└── example.cpython-311-darwin.so
```

And it seems fine. Note that setuptools + manual CMake addition, scikit-build, and scikit-build-core all do not support editable installs (`-e`/`--editable`) since Setuptools 64. If you force the old implementation, it might sort-of work, but really isn't ideal still - you aren't getting much "editable" out of it. Scikit-build-core will have a proper editable installation mechanism soon (within a month or two).

Comment: Thanks for looking into my posts! The lack of editable support sounds like a deal-breaker to me, however... I have packages comprised of both C++ and Python code. I'd like to be able to have the Python-based modules (such as `OtherModule` in this example) be editable. How should I go about it with `scikit-build`? Would you advice I split my modules so I can `pip install .` the C++ ones and `pip install -e .` the Python ones, for instance?

Comment: I think you can use `SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES="legacy-editable"` to restore the (not great, but hopefully not complete broken) legacy behavior (I think it can even be set via os.environ in setup.py). Scikit-build-core will be solving this first, I think, hopefully very soon, and when scikit-build classic will likely get support when scikit-build-core becomes its new backend.